# Как лучше всего запускать процесс командной строки?

Tags: c#

Как лучше всего запускать процесс для командной строки/powershell, если нужно запустить его, дождаться выполнения одной команды и завершить его? пробовал так и через `Process.Start()`:

```
    class FastProcess
    {
        public static void Start(string FileName, string InputWriteLine)
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

                process.Start();

                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(InputWriteLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так? [Process.WaitForExit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit)

Comment: @ГеннадийП попробовал, поток не освобождается  после завершения команды

Comment: Задача не тривиальная, но [есть вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541090/12888024) для CMD, ваша задача - частный случай того, что умеет тот код. Хотя быть может вам `/C` подойдет - `Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates`

Comment: @aepot на самом деле тривиальная. Нужно запускать не процесс консоли, а саму команду через процесс.старт

Comment: @Andrew из вопроса автора не понятно, что именно ему нужно, может ему нужно интерактивно взаимодействовать с консолью. Он же зачем-то использует `StandardInput` вместо аргументов.

Comment: Вы пробовали запустить `cmd.exe /C` + ваши аргументы?

Comment: @aepot, попробовал, спасибо, запустилось как нужно

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - открывать процесс самой команды которая тебе нужна вместе с параметрами:

```
//путь к программе, параметры запуска
Process.Start("ping.exe", "8.8.8.8");
```

---

Если же нужна последовательность команд, то тебе проще создать батник и запустить его.

вот пример файла:

```
@echo off
ping 8.8.8.8
ping 8.8.4.4
ping 8.8.1.1
```

Если нужно что б не закрывался сам а по нажатию любой клавиши делаем

```
@echo off
ping 8.8.8.8
pause
```

Comment: Не знаю, подойдет ли такой вариант, дело в том, что этот процесс должен будет использоваться еще и powershell'ом, да и приложение должно компилироваться в единый екзешник

Comment: замени батник на павершеловский скрипт .ps1 и запускай его. А то что должен быть единый файл - ну создавай в рантайме сам файл скрипта во временной папке, а потом удаляй. :) Костыль, но сработает более чем и в реализации более чем просто. Вобщем - не вижу пока что никаких препятствий к такой реализации.